# Limit client number of products order

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, shopping-cart, cart-rule, messages

How can I limit the client to only buy 4 products per month.

For example I have product A, B, C, D and E.

The costumer makes an order and puts in the cart product A,B and C.

In the same month the costumer can only put in cart product A,B,C and D or E. But not D,E and A. Because the costumer already ordered product A,B and C and he can only buy 4 products per month. The next month he can make an order with A,B,D,E , but in the same month he can only buy one of those 4 and he won't be able to buy the other one. How can I do that ?

I got this

```
    $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
    ->load();
```

to get the orders, but how can I find the products purchased so I can check if he putted any product in the cart the he shouldn't ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am again, You can use the below function to get order count of the customer,

```
  $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());

    echo $count = $orders->getSize();

  if($count >= '4')
 {
// your stuff here
exit;
}
else {
return true;
}
```

Here you can write condition like the above..

**Update:**

You can check if the product is exist in order by below code,

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
         foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
         $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();

        }


        $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $productId));

         echo $orders->getSize();
```

Comment: But I need to check if the product in the cart was purchased previously. And if the costumer already have the 4 products.

Comment: I updated  my answer, check it..!

Comment: I explained wrong. I need to check if the product in the cart was already bought in previous orders. Sorry

Comment: And what is the event so I can do an extension ?

Comment: It doesn't need any events ...You can use it in same function ..

Comment: But how can I join that to the other function ? I have it this way http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/98097118 !

Comment: Sorry I don't know what's problem in this..Just use this bit of code anywhere in yr function ..This ll return the order size that product exists in cart ..

Comment: Sorry about that, I've already done it, use booleans to see what had been triggered and at the bottom of the code I showed the warnings depending of what conditions have been triggered

Comment: Have you notice that I had been changed the model to         $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');

not         $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')

Comment: How can I get the name and quantity of each product for every order from a customer within an interval time ?